# is it possible to use something like "reloadData" between 2 scroll views in iOS to keep the data loaded efficiently?

Tags: ios, view, scroll, scrollview, reloaddata

I have 2 scroll views. When click one of the buttons in the first Scroll view, some images related to this button will be retrieves from a plist and loaded into the second Scroll view.Is it possible to use something like "reloadData" between the 2 scroll views in iOS to keep the data loaded efficiently? Customers may click the buttons in the first Scroll view frequently, so we have to consider its efficiency and low system cost. Some sample code is appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Scroll views don't have any data to load, so the shortest answer is no, there is nothing like that.

However, I do assume you do your loading somewhere on your code, perhaps some research on how to do some low consuming loading or use multi-threading for your image loading process? My bet is that the user will be OK if when he tries to load an image on your second scroll view he gets an empty view with a little loading icon for half a second before the image is displayed.

Comment: thanks Ismael for your prompt reply. I want to achieve the effect as in the first 2 screenshots of iPhone App from the link : https://itunes.apple.com/jp/app/rna-x-haoreba-2010-summer/id375721798?mt=8     ,   there are 2 vertical Scroll views at the right side. when click one button on the right side scroll view, according items is loaded on the left scroll view. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you just simply make two arrays that hold the data of both scrollviews and make a method that empty the scrollview and add all the data again into (both)scrollviews and if you want to delete any element or data then you delete from scrollview as well as delete from array that hold the data of that scrollview then you just call that function and your scrollview is reloaded :-)

Comment: thanks Waseem Shah! Actually the right " category " scroll view of the RNA App 's images is fixed. But the left scroll view's images is changed when click other image buttons in the right " category " scroll view. Your method of delete elements is applicable to the horizontal scroll view ( the third one).